# scanf problem in input

Tags: c, scanf

hi I am having problems using scanf when reading two strings with spaces consecutively

```
char name[50] = {0};
char address[100] = {0};
char name1[50] = {0};
char address1[100] = {0};
int size = 0;
//input = fopen("/dev/tty","r+");
//output = fopen("/dev/tty","w");
printf("\nenter the name:");
scanf("%[^\n]s",name);
//fgets(name,sizeof(name),input); // this works fine
printf("\nenter the address:");
scanf("%[^\n]s",address);
//fgets(address,sizeof(address),input); // this works fine
```

the input for address is not taken at all.. maybe it takes the return key as an input?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The newline (`'\n'`) character is still on the input stream after the first `scanf` call, so the second `scanf` call sees it immediately, and immediately stops reading.

I notice that you mention `fgets` in comments - why not use that ? It does what you want to do quite well.

Comment: maybe for portability I dont know if in windows you can open the console/terminal. maybe i can use gets but is it safe?

Comment: @dasman - `fgets` is part of the C standard and fully portable.

Comment: @dasman : you can pass `stdin` as the third parameter to `fgets` to read from standard input. Just remember that the newline character will be in the string, so you'll probably want to sanitize (trim etc.) the input.

Comment: No, `gets()` is not safe.  *Never* use it.

Comment: @dasman: Yes, you can open a console window in Windows. If the program was not a console program, I assume that scanf() would not work properly either.

Comment: More information: `gets()` cannot be used safely because it provides no way to limit the length of the input line.  You can write `char line[1000]; gets(line);` and your cat can cause a buffer overflow by sitting on your keyboard.  [Relevant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gets).  (I would have explained that earlier, but I didn't feel like typing all that on my iPad.)

Comment: @dasman: To expand on what Rudy wrote, all the standard C input routines (`fgets`, `getchar`, `getc`, `fgetc`, `scanf`, etc. -- even the accursed `gets`) read from `stdin`, the standard input stream, either by default or if you specify `stdin` as an argument.  On Windows, that's probably going to be a console window reading from the keyboard.

Answer (score 2):

You have a couple of problems.

As @sander pointed out, you're not doing anything to clear the newline out of the input buffer.

You've also used `%[^\n]s` -- but the `s` isn't needed for (nor it is part of) a scanset conversion. Since it's not part of the conversion, scanf attempts to match that character in the input -- but since you've just read up to a new-line (and not read the newline itself) it's more or less demanding that 's' == '\n' -- which obviously can't be, so the scan fails.

To make this work, you could use something like this:

```
scanf("%49[^\n]%*c", name);
scanf("%99[^\n]%*c", address);
```

As to why you'd want to use this instead of `fgets`, one obvious reason is that it does *not* include the trailing (and rarely desired) newline character when things work correctly. `fgets` retaining the newline does give you one result that can be useful though: the newline is present if and only if the entire content of the line has been read. If you're really concerned about that (e.g., you want to resize your buffer and continue reading if the name exceeds the specified size) you can get the same with `scanf` as well -- instead of using `%*c` for the second conversion, use `%c`, and pass the address of a `char`. You read the entire line if and only if you've read a newline into that char afterwards.